# Simple example of MVVM design pattern in Java without designing any UI (Swing, JavaFX etc)

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvvm

I want to understand MVVM design pattern in Java but I don't want to design a GUI (view) using Swing or JavaFX. I am unable to find any such example in Java on internet. Most of the examples of MVVM are in Android. Can you provide a simple example for the same so that I don't require to learn Swing or JavaFX to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX and Swing exist to make it easier to create GUIs. Trying to create a GUI without such libraries would create much, much more complex code that would not be easier to understand. You could create a pseudo-code program, but then it wouldn't be java-specific. I also doubt it would provide much more understanding than just reading about the general philosophy about MVVM.

Comment: Ohh ok. So, can you share some link or an example of MVVM pattern in Java?